# Mobile Viewing for Google Apps Script with Bootstrap

Tags: mobile, google-apps-script, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to design a mobile first web app using Google Apps Script.

I would try to replicate the most basic Bootstrap page (http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar) in a Google Apps Script.

This is the way the bootstrap page should render on my mobile device:

[image]

but instead my page loads like this (ie. http://goo.gl/yZpgUg):

[image]

This is my code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService
      .createTemplateFromFile('index')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.NATIVE);
}
```

My index.html is copied and pasted from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar with CDNs replaced as appropriate.

I figured HtmlService.SandboxMode.**NATIVE** was important to get this to work but doesn't seem to work.

Dear world - any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers.

**UPDATE 1 - (THANKS FOR YOUR RESPONSES!)**

in IFRAME:
[image]

IFRAME console errors (2):
[image]

NATIVE console errors (lots):
[image]

Bottom line - clearly GAS is not liking it and doesn't seem super straight forward - I've ended up turning the GAS into an API which returns JSONP from the spreadsheet I need - much more straight forward.  Thank you for all your help!

Comment: What does the browser console report?

Comment: you tried `SandboxMode.IFRAME` ?

Comment: Console reports and .IFRAME results listed above. Thanks!

Comment: Could you share your working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently Google can't load Bootstrap from their server, try copying everything to GAS and include in the page as explained in [best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/best-practices#separate_html_css_and_javascript). Also switch back to IFRAME when testing.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I've looked at that best practices page - it is helpful but I think the main problem is that you can't get at the <head> attributes through GAS through either the NATIVE/IFRAME settings - or at least I don't know how to do this - as a result the "<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">" in the index.html file is not displayed properly.  Let me know if you know how to edit the displayed header region through GAS.  Cheers.

Comment: Not a chance, no <head> or <body> tags attributes change, CAJA won't allow it, if you place either inside the HTML they will be replaced, but there is always a workaround. I've managed to make Bootstrap work on IFRAME tough, dunno about mobile.

Comment: That's what I figured - bootstrap seems to be working - just the mobile viewing/viewport is not working.  Understood that CAJA won't allow it.

Answer (score 3):

I know you decided to go another route, but I got this to work in the same scenario. You can simply add the meta tag on the GAS code using the following code:

var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('**Hello, world!**');

output.addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');

So when you serve up your html in doGet add the meta tag. Check out this link for more information: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#addMetaTag(String,String)

Comment: in addition, to @Arun Aruljothi, CAJA will remove the viewpoint tag, therefor you need to programatically add while rendering your gas hosted page.